# Bootstrapping and Configuring Spring. Difference between Configuring ApplicationContext in JavaSE and JavaEE

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, applicationcontext

I am learning Spring framework, and getting an application context is really hard to understand for me. I understand that Bootstrapping Spring in JavaEE and JavaSE is different. I have bootstrapped my application using XML. Now I am not sure how and where to get the application context. I have done it in Servlet's config method for now. The problem with that is, I can't access that context outside of config. I really need some education on this ApplicationContext topic. Is it right to assume that ApplicationContext is a handle by which we can access beans in xml file from Java Code?

Thanks.

Comment: [Understanding Application Context](https://spring.io/understanding/application-context)?

Comment: That's part of the question. Where should you generally define application context in servlet? Would it be a good idea to do it in init method?